# When is finalization method in unit called?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I have an app that recently crashed and I was able to get its callstack using EurekaLog. What I noticed is that an unit finalization was called but the app did not close and continued to work.

AFAIK, finalization sections are only called when the app terminates. But that was not what happened to me.

Does anyone knows why a finalization method was called when it was not supposed to do so?

**EDIT**

This app does not use any dlls or bpls.

**EDIT2**

Is it possible that a thread when finished could call finalization?

Comment: comment the line, see if the problem persists, if so, then your problem is in a different place, otherwise, you have to provide more info regarding the function, usually eureka is right...

Comment: i am trying to reproduce the problem for almost 2 hours and i got nothing so far.

Comment: If you can't reproduce it, then this question is pretty pointless. `finalization` happens at termination time.

Comment: @RafaelColucci you're not trying hard enough, most likely there's a special case that you're missing, start from scratch with a different approach, something you haven't already done

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Why is the question pointless? Just because I cant reproduce the error it does not mean that the problem does not exist. Or when a customer calls you with an error and you cant reproduce you tell him/her that his/her call is pointless?

Comment: @DorinDuminica Trust me, I am trying hard.

Comment: Asking the question here is pointless. There's clearly no way we can help.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I do not agree. There is always an way of helping. Maybe I am missing something, or you guys could come with an way of detecting how the heck the finalization unit gets called when it should not.

Comment: I think the only help we can give is what Mason says in his comment.

Comment: Re: edit2 - No. Have a search on 'FinalizeUnits' in system.pas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finalizations are called in two places.  The most common one is when the application terminates.  But they can also be called when a DLL (or BPL) is unloaded, which happens automatically when the application terminates but can also happen in the middle of the program running if the code explicitly unloads it.

Is it possible that that's what's going on?

Comment: Nops. This app does not use any dlls or bpls.

Comment: Then either you've got an error in the EurekaLog report itself, or your code is following a corrupted function pointer somewhere and ending up in a finalization routine.  Because you never end up there legitimately unless the unit's module is about to be unloaded.